# How to add icons only to certain buttons?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I currently have this code on my page:

```
$( ":button").button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus"
                }
            });
```

That makes all of the buttons have plus signs.

Is there a way to only make certain buttons have plus signs, but have the rest of the buttons not have plus signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the buttons to a class and use

```
$('.class:button')
```

instead of

```
$(':button')
```